# Pressing home when app is also launcher it stops showing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-launcher

when our app is manually started activity on resume gets instances to activity, fragment manager etc... everything works. If it is started from BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast also works as planned.

But when i set is as a launcher and i start it manually and then press home, on every home press i get activity on resume ( and first activity on resume from home press gets a new activity instance, fragment manager instance) but there is the catch, our we can trigger some status display from background and when trying to show the fragment it says it calls it onresume etc... but the fragment isn't shown. Like it is still being displayed on previous instance of activity. Our app is singletask, so only one activity should be alive. What am i missing?